# JSF - get parameter from request URL?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I start learning JSF.

Let us assume that, there is url: domain.lol/article/bla-bla-bla where bla-bla-bla is a title of article. 
Also I have a file article.xhtml to show content of this article.

And now I'm considering what may I do after getting request like that, to extract bla-bla-bla and redirect to article.xhtml page to show bla-bla article.

How can I do that?

Comment: Tried [PrettyFaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces)?

Answer (score -1):

To build links like this: example.com/articles/title-one you can use [urlrewrite library](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for that.

Simple rule can look like this:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/articles/title$</from>
   <to>/articles/title.xhtml</to>
</rule>
```

If you just starting to learn JSF I suggest to use [this](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) tutorial to learn in small steps how it works.